# Update records from MySQL to SQL Server

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have the same tables in two different databases, one is on MySQL and the other one on SQL Server. I want to run a query to get the data from a MySQL table to a SQL Server table to update the records on daily basis.

E.g. I have 200 record in MySQL today by tomorrow it might be 300. I want to update 200 records today and the only 100 new record tomorrow.

Can any one help me please?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to provide an example of what you have tried at least. You can't expect someone else to do all the work for you.

Comment: what you've tried?

Answer (score 1):

Probably the best way to manage this is from the SQL Server database.  This allows that database to *pull* the data in every day, rather than having the MySQL database *push* the data.

The place to start is by linking the servers.  Start with the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/linked-servers/linked-servers-database-engine) on the subject.  Next, set up a job in SQL Server Agent.  This job would do the following:

1. Connect to the MySQL server.
2. Load the data into a staging table.
3. Validate the data.
4. Update or insert the data into the final table.

You can schedule this job to run every day.

Note that 200 or 300 records is very small by the standards of databases (unless the records are really, really big).

Comment: Hi, Thank you for  the reply.

Comment: HI, I have a 9 million row in the table it grows every day. I connected data bases and  scheduled the jobs by using azure data factory. instead of wiping the data in the destination database i just want to update the latest records only. can you please help me on this. there is no time or date stamp column in the table ?

Comment: @UmaShankar . . . Export the data and re-import it.  Or, design a proper application that can replicate the data -- that would include unique ids and timestamps.

Answer (score 0):

There is no straight forward way for this. But you can approach this way

1. Use `mysqldump` to create a dump of the table data.
2. restore that in your SQL Server in a temporary / auxiliary table.
3. perform the update to main table `JOIN` with that temporary table.
4. delete the temporary table

Comment: HI, I have a 9 million row in the table it grows every day. I connected data bases and scheduled the jobs by using azure data factory. instead of wiping the data in the destination database i just want to update the latest records only. can you please help me on this. there is no time or date stamp column in the table ?